# prepareForSegue takes me to a blank page

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I have to View Controllers (UpcomingReleaseViewController and ReleaseController).

I'm using JSON to populate my app.

The main page from my app is UpcomingReleasesViewController, once you click on a cell its supposed to take you to the Release page and show you more information, but for some reason every time you click on a cell it takes you to a blank page.

**ReleaseView.h**

```
@interface ReleaseViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *releaseView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *release_name;
@end
```

**ReleaseView.m**

```
@interface ReleaseViewController ()

@end

@implementation ReleaseViewController

@synthesize releaseView = _releaseView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.releaseView.text = self.release_name;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**UpcomingReleaseViewController.m**

```
#import "UpcomingReleasesViewController.h"
#import "UpcomingRelease.h"
#import "ReleaseViewController.h"

@interface UpcomingReleasesViewController ()

@end

@implementation UpcomingReleasesViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *upcomingReleasesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://obscure-lake-7450.herokuapp.com/upcoming.json"];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:upcomingReleasesURL];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    self.upcomingReleases = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSArray *upcomingReleasesArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_releases"];

    for (NSDictionary *upcomingReleaseDictionary in upcomingReleasesArray) {
        UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [UpcomingRelease upcomingReleaseWithReleaseName:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_name"]];
        upcomingRelease.release_price = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_price"];
        upcomingRelease.release_date = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"];
        upcomingRelease.thumbnail = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        upcomingRelease.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"url"]];
        [self.upcomingReleases addObject:upcomingRelease];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [self.upcomingReleases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:upcomingRelease.thumbnailURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    cell.imageView.image = image;
    cell.textLabel.text = upcomingRelease.release_name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ — $%@",[upcomingRelease formattedDate], upcomingRelease.release_price];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - View Upcoming Release

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRelease"] ) {
        ReleaseViewController *rvc = (ReleaseViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        rvc.release_name = [self.upcomingReleasesArray objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    }
}


@end
```

The Storyboard Segue is named correctly (showRelease) and I linked the UITextView to my ReleaseViewController (releaseView). Maybe is has something to do with the upcomingReleasesArray? I'm new to iOS, i don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: Where do you call the segue? In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Log [self.upcomingReleasesArray objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row] in prepareForSegue to see if it's nil there.

Answer (score 0):

While you want to navigate by clicking on your table cell, you  should use didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method of tableView. And in that method just use the thing you have used in prepareForSegue and remove this prepareForSegue. Because prepareForSegue will be called before going to next View. And didSelect will get called while clicking on cell. You should use prepareForSegue when you want to set any data before calling the next view.